# nolock en read_committed_snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, azure-sql

Tengo un sql server de azure configurado con el esquema insolation level **read_committed_snapshot**
el esquema de insolation level lo veo con el comando DBCC USEROPTIONS , mi duda era si evitar usar nolock con este esquema de inslation level porque no es necesario

para ello hice unas pruebas:

hago un select en una sesion por un producto por id y obtengo como resultado en el campo descricion  la palabra descripcion

```
select  Descripcion from products  where id = 954458
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego en otra sesion hago un transsaccion que seria la sesion bloqueadora y ejecuto con la linea del commit comentado

```
BEGIN TRAN
update  products set 
descripcion = 'test2'
where id = 954458
--COMMIT
--Rollback
```

vuelvo a ejecutar el select de la sesion 1 y en el select siempre accedo al dato no me bloquea  pero obtengo el dato el valor del dato original o sea el valor antes del commit ,y  me devuelve la palabra descripcion.
pero si hago el select con nolock la consulta obtengo el valor nuevo sin haber realizado el commit, es decir obtengo el valor test2.

```
select  Descripcion from products with(nolock)  where id = 9544
```

en otros esquema de insolation me bloqueaba el select  la transaccion
y pensaba que este esquema no necesito el nolock, pero por lo que veo el nolock me trae el dato mas nuevo, no el anterior
entonces es recomendable usar nolock con este nivel de insolation level.o afecta el rendimiento?

Answer (score 0):

Usar `NOLOCK` de manera indiscriminada es una idea terrible. Lo que hace es cambiar el isolation level a `READ UNCOMMITTED` (por lo que no aplicaría el `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT`) y no elimina los locks solo los ignora para la lectura.

Usar NOLOCK es una opción para cuando deseas obtener información sin preocuparte por bloqueos, pero también sin preocuparte por que sea información exacta. `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` es una alternativa a los problemas de bloqueo para sistemas muy activos y tiene sus puntos débiles como para meterle más con los hints `NOLOCK`.

Como lo muestran tus pruebas (y como se detalla en la documentación), los datos regresados por ambos `isolation levels` serán distintos cuando hay transacciones en proceso. `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` trae los datos de como estaban las tablas cuando se inició la consulta sin contar transacciones abiertas. Evita las transacciones abiertas porque aun no es información confiable y pueden ser canceladas.

Comment: hola luis, gracias por contestar  hice una modificacion , con unas  pruebas

Comment: o sea usar nolock en un insolation level READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT no hay que usarlo nunca?,  porque te cambia el level a  READ UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: No digo que no haya que usarlo nunca, pero hay que usarlo solo cuando se quiera leer datos que pertenezcan a transacciones abiertas. Por ejemplo, cuando quieres ver un avance de la carga de información o un conteo rápido de algo que no necesite ser preciso (usuarios conectados, operaciones activas, etc)

Comment: a oka para leer datos sucios que no fueron commiteados serian los casos que comentas  gracias Luis

Comment: pero si tenemos en nolock con el insolation level READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT no tiene sentido la mayoria de las veces , no se si peude afectar el rendimiento , ? generando bloqueos?

Comment: No afecta el rendimiento, porque no se tendrían que generar bloqueos.